# where is the bytecode of an unverfied smart contract in etherscan?

Tags: contract-development, bytecode

Why is the bytecode of the previously unverified smart contract missing from Etherscan?
We can view the bytecode of the unverified smart contract before. But now we can't even see the 'contract' tag by clicking its address

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? When viewing a contract on Etherscan, it should always show the bytecode, whether or not the contract is verified

Comment: Thanks, but you can go and find it , Etherscan has changed, and the bytecode of an unverified smart contract is now missing. that is why I want to figure out